# Did Dagon kill the two angels with her bare hands?

Tags: supernatural

In Supernatural season 12 episode 13- Family Feud- we see Dagon kill two angels. However, it didn't seem clear to me whether she was holding something in her hand when she killed the two angels, or whether she can straight on kill them with her bare hands. There was a youtube video which seemed to show her holding something in her fist if you played it in slow motion, but it's no longer there.

Another reason I thought this (which isn't exactly direct evidence), is that demons have never had the power to directly kill angels without a weapon, even very powerful ones. We see Ramiel having to use the Lance of Michael in order to fatally harm Castiel for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, after season 12 episode 19 "The Future", the answer is yes, Dagon can and does kill angels with her bare hands. It's ambiguous whether that is a general power of Princes of Hell*,or if Lucifer imbued her with some extra angel-killing power on top of her Prince(ess) of Hell status when he entasked her with his Nephalim son, but she definitely can kill angels without having to resort to any hand-held weapons.

*Ramiel had to use the Lance of Michael to harm Castiel, but it could be he wanted to cause him great pain before dying; also, we never see Azazel take on angels